# ¿Cómo insertar cálculos en otra tabla utilizando CASE WHEN THEN...ELSE en una función disparadora?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Soy nuevo en postgres y en general programando. Intento, partiendo de datos en dos tablas (b y c) insertar datos calculados en otra tabla (d) cada vez que se inserte o actualice c. Después del END que cierra el CASE me daba error de síntaxis en o cerca de «END» lo que se debía a que el CASE en pgsql debe cerrar con END CASE; Ahora no obtengo ningún error, pero tampoco logro insertar los cálculos en la tabla d. ¿Alguna idea?

```
CREATE TABLE b (idb int primary key, ba int, bb int, bc int, bd int);
CREATE TABLE c (idc int primary key,ca int, cb int, cc int, cd int, ce int, cf int);
CREATE TABLE d (idd int primary key, sd int, dl int, dm int, ds int, dc int, dt int, tot_d int);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcula_d()
    RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    CASE WHEN b.bb = 7 THEN 
        INSERT INTO d 
        SELECT NEW.idc, 0.5*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0), 0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0), 0.5*COALESCE((NEW).cc,0),
        0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cd,0), 0.1*COALESCE((NEW).ce,0), 0,  0.5*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0)+0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0)+0.5*COALESCE((NEW).cc,0)+0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cd,0)+0.1*COALESCE((NEW).ce,0)
        WHERE c.idc = b.idb;
        RETURN NEW;
    WHEN b.bb = 6 THEN 
        INSERT INTO d 
        SELECT NEW.idc, 0.3*COALESCE((NEW).ca,0),0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0),0.2*COALESCE((NEW).cc,0),0.3*COALESCE((NEW).cd,0),0,0,
        0.3*COALESCE((NEW).ca,0)+0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0)+0.2*COALESCE((NEW).cc,0)+0.3*COALESCE((NEW).cd,0)
        WHERE c.idc = b.idb;
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE 
        RAISE NOTICE 'El valor de bb es incorrecto, bb= %', b.bb;
    END CASE;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER dan
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ca, cb, cc, cd, ce, cf
    ON c
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE calcula_d();
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx! Como sugerencia no relacionada, procura siempre ponerle nombres significativos a las tablas; mantener algo con nombres ca, cb suena un poco a el infierno para quien no cree el cóðigo (o para ti mismo en unos meses cuando intentes saber de qué va cada cosa)

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por las sugerencias. No comprendo bien tu pregunta, pero después de cada CASE ..WHEN...THEN aparece la sentencia INSERT INTO d. Y deseo insertar en todos los campos de la tabla "d".

Comment: Mala mía que no leí bien :) Ahora sí: seguro que esos SELECT van sin FROM? Porque tienen cláusulas en el WHERE que aluden a b. Lo otro, crea un trigger sobre cada tabla y usas la misma trigger function si quieres, pero revisa la condición que vas a usar, porque no es evidente que el trigger reciba un montón de tablas... el trigger sólo recibe NEW y OLD según sea la acción, nada más, no es que de repente tengas b, c y d ahí cargadas en el trigger

Comment: Todavía no había pensado en que necesito otro trigger para cuando se actualice "b". Pero en este caso, suponiendo que solo los valores en "c" puedan cambiar: ¿crees que debo hacer primero un `select bb from b` y sustituir b.bb por bb en el WHEN para pasarle esos valores a la función?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo las pistas que me dió @Alfabravo, buscando y probando, el siguiente código me funcionó:

```
    CREATE TABLE b (idb int primary key, ba int, bb int, bc int, bd int);
    CREATE TABLE c (idc int primary key,ca int, cb int, cc int, cd int, ce int, cf int);
    CREATE TABLE d (idd int primary key, sd int, dl int, dm int, ds int, dc int, dt int, tot_d int);
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcula_d()
        RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
    v_bb b.bb%TYPE;
    v_idb b.idb%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT b.idb,b.bb INTO v_idb,v_bb FROM b WHERE b.idb = NEW.idc;
        CASE WHEN v_bb = 7 THEN INSERT INTO d 
            SELECT NEW.idc, 0.5*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0), 0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0), 0.5*COALESCE((NEW).cc,0),
            0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cd,0), 0.1*COALESCE((NEW).ce,0), 0,  0.5*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0)+0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0)+0.5*COALESCE((NEW).cc,0)+0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cd,0)+0.1*COALESCE((NEW).ce,0);
            RETURN NEW;
            WHEN v_bb = 6 THEN INSERT INTO d 
            SELECT NEW.idc, 0.3*COALESCE((NEW).ca,0),0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0),0.2*COALESCE((NEW).cc,0),0.3*COALESCE((NEW).cd,0),0,0,
            0.3*COALESCE((NEW).ca,0)+0.4*COALESCE((NEW).cb,0)+0.2*COALESCE((NEW).cc,0)+0.3*COALESCE((NEW).cd,0);
            RETURN NEW;
            ELSE RAISE NOTICE 'El valor de bb es incorrecto, bb= %', v_bb;
         END CASE;
    RETURN NULL;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```